# How to implement Customer UserType search in Hybris?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to implement custom **UsersType** search in Hybris. First I have to index the user from  database into solr db, which I know. But, How to display the result which comes from database into Solr DB onto Frontend using say **Users.jsp**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a **UserTypeProvider**. Have look here for an example:

```
hybris\bin\ext-commerce\commerceservices\classes\de\hybris\platform\commerceservices\search\solrfacetsearch\provider\impl\ProductConfigurableValueProvider.class
```

and than you have to do your search with SOLR service, have a look here:

```
hybris\bin\ext-commerce\commercefacades\classes\de\hybris\platform\commercefacades\search\solrfacetsearch\impl\DefaultSolrProductSearchFacade.class
```

and at least you have to set the Provider in the **solr.impex**. Have a look here for examples:

```
hybris\bin\ext-commerce\commercesearch\resources\test\impex\solr.impex
```